# Type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on this scroll function to lock the position while scrolling up or down
and I have encountered below error

```
Type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement'.ts(2322)
```

Could anyone help me resolving this error?

```
scroll = (): void => {
  if (this.isLargerScreenMedia()) {
    this.applyLargeMediaStyles();
  } else {
    const scrollPos: number = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const totalCon: HTMLDivElement =
      this.tripTotalContainer.querySelector('.trip-total-module');
    if (totalCon) {
      if (scrollPos > this.lastScrollPos) {
        //scroll down
        totalCon.style.bottom = '0px';
      } else {
        //scroll up
        totalCon.style.bottom = '27px';
      }
    }
    this.lastScrollPos = scrollPos < 0 ? 0 : scrollPos;
    this.tripTotalContainer.classList.add('sticky-bottom');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`querySelector` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) has a return type of `Element | null` - if no matching element(s) are found, `null` will be returned.

So, this line is causing the error you're seeing, since you're saying that `totalCon` is of type `HTMLDivElement` (without accounting for `null`):

```
const totalCon: HTMLDivElement = this.tripTotalContainer.querySelector('.trip-total-module');
```

It looks like the rest of your code already checks if `totalCon` is "falsy", so you could resolve this by just removing the explicit type declaration:

```
const totalCon = this.tripTotalContainer.querySelector('.trip-total-module');
```

Alternatively, you could make the explicit type declaration match the return type of `querySelector`:

```
const totalCon: HTMLDivElement | null = this.tripTotalContainer.querySelector('.trip-total-module');
```